# Inheritance: constructor, initialize C like array member of base class in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor

Consider following code:

```
struct Base //in my real scenario Base class can not be changed
{
    int a;
    double b[10];
};

struct Child : Base
{
    Child(int aa, double bb[10]) : Base{aa} {}     //This works fine
    Child(int aa, double bb[10]) : Base{aa, bb} {} //this is not working
};
```

The second constructor of child is not working. I get the error "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer". 
How can I initialize `b` in `Child` without changing Base class (for example using vector instead of c-like array, i am not allowed to do that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Child`'s constructor, `bb` is not an array: because of [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), it's just a pointer. And you can't initialize an array (`b` in `Base`) with a pointer.

Using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) in both classes instead of raw arrays would solve your problem:

```
struct Base
{
    int a;
    std::array<double, 10> b;
};

struct Child : Base
{
    Child(int aa, std::array<double, 10> bb) : Base{aa, bb} {}
};
```

However, since you mention that `Base` cannot be modified, you will have to copy the elements manually (in the general case, you can also [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) them, although there is no point with fundamental types):

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int a;
    double b[10];
};

struct Child : Base {
    Child(int aa, std::array<double, 10> bb) : Base{aa} {
        std::copy(bb.begin(), bb.end(), b);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto child = Child(3, {2, 3, 4});

    for (auto it : child.b) {
        std::cout << it << " ";
    }
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f7b131ac079edea)

You can also do that using a reference instead of `std::array`, but the syntax is a bit convoluted:

```
Child(int aa, double const (&bb)[10]) : Base{aa} {
    std::copy(&bb[0], &bb[10], b);
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True, but knowing you can can't hurt... probably? Anyway, it could be used for heavier types.

Comment: I'll rephrase - you can't move doubles.

Comment: Sure, I meant "apply `std::move` to the elements", whatever their type is.

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks